# ADO.Net dataset doesn't fetch generated identity to datatable after update

Tags: c#, ado.net

Didn't find a useful answer to my problem, so maybe try my luck on here. I'm trying to add a record to a table in an MSAccess mdb-file with a C# Ado.Net Dataset. Everything goes fine until I try to add a new row to another table that is referenced with a foreign key. This doesn't work as planned because the objectrow still has a default '-1' id-value after I updated the datatable with the previous new row, and thusly can not add a new row because of the foreign key.
The id-value should be updated as the column is of the auto-increment/identity-variant-type of MSaccess.

I used generic names cause I wrote this in another language...

```
public void addObject(Object o)
        {

        ds.objects.Clear(); //clear datatable where ds is reference to dataset
        Data.DBManagerDataSet.objectRow row = ds.objects.NewobjectRow();

        FillRowWithVariables(row, o); //fill row with some random variables

        ds.objects.Rows.Add(rij);
        taObjects.Update(ds.objects); //tell tableadapter to update objects

        Object2 p = AddObjectWithSomeRandomVariables(o.RandomVariable);

        Data.DBManagerDataSet.object_otherobjectRow linkrow = ds.object_otherobject.Newobject_otherobjectRow(); //new row to reference the other one

        linkrow.object_id = row.object_id;
        linkrow.otherobject = p.Id;
        ds.object_otherobject.Rows.Add(linkrow);
        taobject_otherobject.Update(ds.object_otherobject);

        }
```

Some help?

Answer (score 2):

There is an MSDN article covering how to do this (including sample code for Access at the bottom): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx

Edit:

The way that is recommended by the MSDN is to add an event handler to the `OleDbDataAdapter.RowUpdated` event that will retrieve the autonumber for the inserted row:

```
private static void OnRowUpdated(object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Conditionally execute this code block on inserts only.
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmdNewID = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection);
        // Retrieve the Autonumber and store it in the CategoryID column.
        e.Row["CategoryID"] = (int)cmdNewID.ExecuteScalar();
        e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so other users will have some idea of what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Think of what happens if that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Please take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).